# bootstrap 3 logo slogan and nav collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav, graphical-logo

I'm trying to create a layout where I have a logo on the left and a slogan pane with the navigation bar under it on the right.  See picture #1.

[image]

When the screen begins to get narrower I want the navigation pane to drop below the logo and slogan and allow the slogan to just get narrower while remaining on the right side even as the navigation bar collapses.  See picture #2.

[image]

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: See this related answer, it has a few fiddles that might be a good jumping off point: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13372707/1754037

Answer (score 1):

You could use two media types for it.

In first case use *etc.* **@media screen and (max-width: 960px)** and write your css.

In second case *etc.* **@media screen and (max-width: 640px)** use another css styles for your position. And don't forget to add clear div/css in these statement.